# How to retrieve and list selected option array angular typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, asp.net-web-api

Hi im trying to retrieve the array of the selected option currently only the company name is working because i can get only one value from event.target.value or ngModel i would like to know how to do it
If you know a good way to do it i would like to know thanks a lot if you mind to keep it simple will be glad because im still learning:)
(btw the array is coming from db)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from '../_models/company';
import { CompanyService } from '../_services/company.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-company',
  templateUrl: './companies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companies.component.css']
})
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {

  companies: Company[];
  selectedCompany = [];

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }




  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCompanies();

  }

  loadCompanies() {
    this.companyService.getCompanies().subscribe((companies: Company[]) => {
      this.companies = companies;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  // selectedChangeHandler(event: any) {
  //   this.selectedCompany = event.target.value;
  // }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 mt-5 bd-sidebar">
  <label for="">Select Company</label> <br>

  <select id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany"  >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let value of companies" value="{{value.name}}">{{value.name}}</option>
    

  </select>
  <p>
    <span>
      You Selected:{{selectedCompany}}
    </span>
  </p>
</div>

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{selectedCompany}}</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Company address here</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Company estimated revenue </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want to push a company to selectedCompany when it is selected?

Comment: why u use an array as a selected company? u can use just Company type for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this by changing the data type of  `selectedCompany = [];` to  `selectedCompany:Company`

and after that u need to change below line

```
 <option *ngFor="let value of companies" value="{{value.name}}">{{value.name}}</option>
```

to

```
<option *ngFor="let value of companies" [Value]="value">{{value.name}}</option>
```

Comment: Yeah but now its "[object Object]"

Comment: i didn't get u? what is [object object] ?

Comment: try[value] instead of [ngValue]

Comment: Yeah but now its "[object Object]" Never mind you solved it for me i did selectedCompany.address :) thanks alot